# Using Rx to give current view of combined live + historic data to subscribers

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactive

I have a wpf app that consumes a live trades feed. When the screen opens I fetch the current list of trades from a rest service and display on a grid. Once this has loaded I then subsribe to updates to these trades by using Rx (websockets underneath this).

The problem is that the trades data is now needed on other independent screens across the app - these will opened at different times but i want them all to have the same data in their grids.

I'm thinking perhaps create a TradeData class that the viewmodels can all share that would put all the trades into a buffer of sorts. It would expose a GetCurrentState() method used when each view loads. After load they could then subscribe to a 'TradeUpdates' IObservable from that point on for updates.

I'm slightly bothered by having both GetCurrentState() AND then a TradeUpdates' IObservable.  Is there a better cleaner way that I'm missing using rx or otherwise? 
Note that users only care about seeing latest trade status, not how we arrived there.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why can't you simply bind the grids with your trades source?

Comment: reasonable suggestion- but each screen aggregates the data a little differently and decorates it with other fields before displaying. So I think this will make it tricky

Comment: Depending on the amount of data you have have you looked at the `.Collect()` operator?